# Delphi editor. Tabs instead Spaces

Tags: delphi, tabs, ide, delphi-5

I use Delphi 5 and I have one interesting question...

If you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key when cursor is at the string's end Delphi IDE automatically aligns cursor position at the new line to the first word at the previous line.

But space between begin of new line and cursor position will be filled with SPACE chars.
How to change this behaviour? I want some amount of TAB characters from begin of new line to the cursor position, as notepad++ do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Under Environment Options → Editor:

[image]

There are some options you should check:

- **Use tab character**. Inserts tab characters when you press TAB in the Code Editor. If not checked, pressing TAB inserts spaces. To view tab characters, select *Show tab character*.
- **Smart tab**. Tabs to the first non-whitespace character in the preceding line.

Comment: Indeed. Optimal fill will use as many tabs as necessary, if the other setting is set. Note that tabs stops must be set to 2 (or whatever value you want to indent), as shown.